# AngularJS Bootstrap datepicker error

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a datepicker in my phonegap app with angular ui bootstrap.

```
<h4>Popup</h4>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

I'm getting this errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/uib/template/datepicker/datepicker.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: The HTTP 404 Not Found error means that the webpage you were trying to reach could not be found on the server.

Comment: Yes I know, but where can I find this file (datepicker.html)?

Comment: it's part of bootstrap framework. include angular-ui. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 published versions of the library, 1 with templates and 1 without.  A description of the difference can be found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#build-files).  I suspect you are not loading the template (-tpls-) version.